# Email subscribe to tag sets always uses the same subject line

Tags: bug, status-completed, email-notification

The email notifier always sends the notification with the same exact subject line. As a result, Gmail bundles them all together as the same "conversation".

So after only a few days being subscribed to some tag set, I get this in my inbox:

[image]

Since I have a filter to label such messages and skip the inbox, and since I (like many users) don't delete messages but archive them, the end result is a [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) on my Gmail :)

[image]

It's 14 by now, but it will probably grow very big very soon.

The easy fix is to add a date to the subject line.

Comment: daamn, that was a quick fix. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.  The subject line now looks like:

"12/22 New questions in [your] tag set - Stack Exchange"

Comment: But there are only 12 months in a year...What if I don't write my dates backwards?

Answer (score 0):

Are you proposing that *daily* emails get a date in the subject line?

Because for the

- every 3 hours
- every 15 minutes

case, what you're seeing is what I would consider to be correct behavior.

I can see for daily summaries where this might not be desirable, though.

Comment: Actually, adding the date for the 15 minute or 3 hour emails seems like a good fix, because then they get grouped together for that day (instead of 96 emails flooding your inbox)